# MinIO mc client Error: dial tcp: lookup minio on 192.168.2.254:53: no such host

Tags: raspberry-pi, minio

I'm running a MinIO server instance on my Raspberry Pi 4 (cross compiled for ARMv7):

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./minio server data/
Endpoint: http://169.254.65.231:9000  http://192.168.2.49:9000  http://172.17.0.1:9000  http://172.18.0.1:9000  http://192.168.32.1:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000               
RootUser: minioadmin 
RootPass: minioadmin 

Browser Access:
   http://169.254.65.231:9000  http://192.168.2.49:9000  http://172.17.0.1:9000  http://172.18.0.1:9000  http://192.168.32.1:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000              

Command-line Access: https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-client-quickstart-guide
   $ mc alias set myminio http://169.254.65.231:9000 minioadmin minioadmin

Object API (Amazon S3 compatible):
   Go:         https://docs.min.io/docs/golang-client-quickstart-guide
   Java:       https://docs.min.io/docs/java-client-quickstart-guide
   Python:     https://docs.min.io/docs/python-client-quickstart-guide
   JavaScript: https://docs.min.io/docs/javascript-client-quickstart-guide
   .NET:       https://docs.min.io/docs/dotnet-client-quickstart-guide
Detected default credentials 'minioadmin:minioadmin', please change the credentials immediately using 'MINIO_ROOT_USER' and 'MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD'
IAM initialization complete
```

On the same Pi, I then run the Minio Client with `mc config host add ...` :

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~/code/pi_eye $ mc config host add minio "http://minio:9000" minioadmin minioadmin --api S3V4
Added `minio` successfully.
```

After this however, I'm stuck with this error:

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~/code/pi_eye $ mc ls minio
mc: <ERROR> Unable to list folder. Get "http://minio:9000/": dial tcp: lookup minio on 192.168.2.254:53: no such host
```

Likewise, if I try to access the Minio server using the Python API, I run into the same issue.

So far, I only found quite obscure solutions in other forums, but none worked for my problem.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the server starts it shows you a list of available interfaces you can connect to, e.g.,:

```
http://169.254.65.231:9000  http://192.168.2.49:9000  http://172.17.0.1:9000  http://172.18.0.1:9000  http://192.168.32.1:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

When you added the alias to `mc`, it should have been for one of these interfaces, e.g., `mc alias set myminio http://192.168.2.49:9000` .  In your case you did `mc config host add minio "http://minio:9000"`.  Checking the error you pasted, it seems to be complaining about not being able to do a DNS lookup for a host named "minio", so you should either:

- Add a host called "minio" to DNS or to /etc/hosts
- Use an IP address to configure mc

So, seems like a simple issue with name resolution, clear that up and you should be able to connect.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works now! I successfully used `mc config host add minio "http://minio:9000"` before, but it was from within a Docker container while minio was also running inside a container. Therefore, Docker-Compose resolved the hostname. Running everything outside Docker obviously didn't allow me to do that.